# pass a method reference to WebClient.exchangeToMono method

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactive-streams

I am trying to define a generic method which takes `responseHandler` method as parameter and pass it to `exchangeToMono` method to avoid writing the lambda expression in the `exchangeToMono` which is discussed in almost all the internet and SO questions. How can I achieve this, I tried a various ways but it is not working.

```
    public static Function<ClientResponse, Mono<Object>> clientResponseMonoFunction = response1 -> {
    if (response1.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
        return response1.bodyToMono(Object.class);
    } else {
        // Turn to error
        return null;
    }
};




Mono<Object> retriveMono(Function responseHandler) {
        return webClient.method(httpMethod).uri(uri).headers(headers).body(Mono.just(request), Object.class).exchangeToMono(MyTestClass::clientResponseMonoFunction); // This did not i.e. static method reference
```

Nothing is happenning unless I call `subscribe` method, but none of the examples in SO I read so far mentioned to use `subscribe`

Want to understand if I am missing anything or where I am doing wrong